# Make div focusable and apply parent link on select

Tags: css, html

It is possible to make the child of a link, instead of the link itself focusable. But is it also possible to follow the parent link on enter? (without javascript) So in the example below I want to go to Google if I hit enter if the div is focussed.

```css
.padded-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: default;
}
.button {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" class="padded-button" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="button"  tabindex="0">button</div>
</a>
```

Note: I'm trying to create a button that acts like a regular button if you use it with a mouse / keyboard, but have a bigger tap area for touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely possible without `js`. You can apply styles to fake focus on the child element, ie:

```
.padded-button:focus .button{ outline: 3px solid red; }
```

But if you have actual focus on a child element of an anchor tag, pressing enter will not bubble up to the parent.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lentqf4u/

Comment: Yes it already gets the right focus, but if I have the div focussed and press enter, it does not follow the link.

Comment: I updated the question a little bit to make it more clear.

Comment: I like the workaround. Is it possible to style the focus as the default focus style of the browser?

Comment: Yeah, just look up what the default is. I would look at the spec or something like normalize css for a sample.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```css
.padded-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: default;
}
.button {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="http://google.com" class="padded-button" >
    <button class="button" type="submit" >button</button>
</form>
```

Based on this: [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-do-i-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

I am not sure about all browsers behaviours, though.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I intended. Now tapping on the form element does not submit the form. Only tapping on the button does.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.padded-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: default;
}
.button {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:focus{ outline: 1px solid red; }
.button:hover{ outline: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<!--<a href="http://google.com" class="padded-button" tabindex="-1">
    <div tabindex="2" class="button" focus="true">button</div>
</a>-->
<form method="post" action="http://google.com">
    <button class="button" type="submit">button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This does not work. If the div has focus and I press enter, I don't go to google.

Comment: Why? remove href. Why need href?

Comment: or else <a href="http://google.com" class="padded-button" tabindex="-1" target="_blank">
    <div tabindex="2" class="button" focus="true">button</div>
</a>

Comment: Sorry, I think you don't get what I want to achieve. I want to make it possible to use 'tab' to go to the div and use the enter key on the div to go to google.com.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. The code below shows that if you click or focus the div it will redirect to the parent link. You can make the div look like a button just by altering it's `CSS`. Also you can increase the focusing or clicking area by increasing the `height` and `width` `CSS attribute`.

```css
#btn
{
  width:100px;
    height:100px;
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.co.in">
  <div id="btn">click me
    </div>
  </a>
```

Just make sure you don't have any other button or link inside the parent `a tag`. Also it is not a good practice to wrap a `div` inside `a tag` in `HTML 4.01`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ehm... now the focus is on the link, not on the div.